# Can't find django-html in "Select Language Mode" in VS Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-templates

I'm trying to set django-html as the language for my *.html files so that I can use the snippets for python template literals but I can't find it anywhere.

When I look for django html by clicking on "Select Language Mode" in the lower right corner I don't get any result:
[Here's is a screenshot of the search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9O3K.png),
[Another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbSWP.png)

However, I've seen in a video that this should be possible:
[screenshot with the search from the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn8sO.png)

I'm using VS Code 1.44.1 and Windows 10

Comment: could you please install plugins for same. or what plugin you installed?

Comment: I didn't install any plugin for that, if by plugin you mean vs code extension I only installed Python extension from Microsoft and Pylint

Answer (score 1):

In the extensions (ctrl shift x on windows) searchbar type: django html, and install the top result (Django 1.6.0)

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://github.com/vscode-django/vscode-django
cd vscode-django
npm install
code .
```

Or go to visual studio code extensions and search for django html and select the django html extension developed by Baptiste Darthenay. Install it and if you look at the status bar you will see Django HTML there. If it is not there then click the language mode which could be HTML on the status bar and search for django html in the menu language mode on the top in the visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

You should install Django in vs code from marketplace and add to json:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "**/templates/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements",
    "*.html": "html"
},
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html"
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For example you can elaborate where to add it, and what effect it will have.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what my settings.json looks like inside .vscode folder.

```
{
 "files.associations": {
    "**/templates{/**,*}.html": "django-html",
 },
 "emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "django-html": "html"
 }
}
```

This will make vscode interpret that whenever it encounters a "template" folder any .html file inside will be considered a django html.